# Timeouts after SSL

Tags: https

We recently received an email from our web host saying that they had identified a problem with our SSL certificate and they would reissue another certificate for free to resolve this.

Prior to the reissue we were receiving security warnings in the browser. Reinstalling the certificate seemed to fix this, however we have been receiving timing out notifications in the browser when trying to access the website (conwayfish) ever since.

We've asked our host about this and there response has been it is a networking issue and they can access the site without problems from their location, and they have provided evidence of this.

Both the client and I have tried different ISPs to access the site but all of them are receive timeouts. I'm totally stumped at why we can't reach the site. We have tried traceroute and navigating to other sites on the grid host which also seem to be problematic. I'm not sure what to do next as I can't see how the certificate failure and network errors could be related.

Comment: Before editing your question to remove the URL (one of the rules here) I checked and you are correct, the site does time out.  It is a network issue and I would contact mediatemple who seem to have something to do with the hosting.

Comment: Thanks Steve, we have mentioned this to Media Temple many times, but they have consistently pushed back with "our traceroutes suggest that the problem is maybe with our ISP or networking" and not their servers. Strangely we've had some success reaching the site via VPN and they've also sent us this test [link](https://geopeeker.com/fetch/?url=conwayfish.com.au) which shows the site loading fine from many different countries. The site has been down for days now so it's good to have some other opinions at this stage. Cheers

Comment: My ISP is Exetel, if you happen to be using them (I am in Oz too) then they are the problem.

Comment: Thanks Steve that helps. We have tried IINET, Internode and Vodaphone so far. I believe they maybe all on the TPG network. We are in Melbourne so it maybe a local networking issue, though our trace routes seemed to time out at MT. I still find it strange that the site was running perfectly before the SSL errors, but I can't think of a technical connection.

Comment: I see a big red flag when a cert needs to be re-issued by a web host. fwiw, I am aware of a well known developer who dropped MT due to issues he had with them.

Comment: Thanks Rob, apparently they had a software issue that invalidated certificates, resulting in our users receiving invalid certificate warnings, obviously a trust issue for a ecommerce site. I've generally had good experiences with MT support, we've just hit a wall here, which will probably result in the client being forced to move the site. Unfortunately we had to do this a month ago with their Wordpress hosting as they had blocked requests on a port we needed to use.

Comment: Just an update on this. Media Temple have come back to us with a response that a level3 server is los angeles is responsible for the timeouts. We have successfully visited the site via a proxy so this does seem like a reasonable explanation.

Comment: After disabling our https in mod rewrite, the site started to load for the first time in four days on http. Which means it is probably not an external networking issue as suggested and more likely an issue with traffic coming in on the SSL port. I've passed this on to MT, but they have been unable to pinpoint the issue. Unfortunately this means we have to move the site.

Comment: I fail to understand why removing the URL from the question is a good thing, because, on the contrary, if we had full details we could have made tests and see better your issues.